# Pygame - smpeg does not find Python headers

Tags: python, pygame

I've been trying to install `Pygame` for days now, and the only dependency missing is `smpeg`. I get the following output:

```
brew install --HEAD smpeg
==> Installing dependencies for smpeg: gobject-introspection, gdk-pixbuf,
==> Installing smpeg dependency: gobject-introspection
==> Building source; bottle blocked by python requirement
==> Downloading http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/gobject-introspection/1.4
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/gobject-introspection-1.40.0.tar.xz
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gobject-introspection/1.40.0
checking for python script directory... ${prefix}/lib/python2.7/site-packages
checking for python extension module directory... ${exec_prefix}/lib/python2.7/sitepackages
checking for headers required to compile python extensions... ./configure: line 14647:      /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/pytho    n-config: No such file or directory
not found
configure: error: Python headers not found
```

I've also tried to `brew edit smpeg`, adding `include.install Dir["*.h"]` above the two `end` at the end of the code, but to no avail.

My `brew doctor` says:

```
Warning: Python is installed at /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework

Homebrew only supports building against the System-provided Python or a
brewed Python. In particular, Pythons installed to /Library can interfere
with other software installs.
```

My `brew list` says:

```
autoconf    git     libgcrypt   mpfr        sdl_mixer
automake    glib        libgpg-error    pkg-config  sdl_ttf
cloog        gmp        libmpc      portmidi    tree
cmake         gnu-getopt    libpng      pwgen       webp
freetype    isl     libtiff     sdl     xz
gettext     jpeg        libtool     sdl_gfx
gfortran    libffi      mercurial   sdl_image
```

`brew --config`:

```
==> Configuration
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
HEAD: 7448fd1532ae1c1709fe2f03ffe0dc188a134b3e
CPU: quad-core 64-bit ivybridge
OS X: 10.9.2-x86_64
Xcode: 5.1.1
CLT: 5.1.0.0.1.1396320587
X11: 2.7.5 => /opt/X11
```

`brew` was `updated` and `upgraded`

I have `Python 2.7.6`

Later I've managed to install `smpeg.h` (and `MPEGfilter.h`) in `Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python` and now when I run `python setup.py install`  from `cd pygame-1.9.1release`, I get:

```
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch i386 -g -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Ddarwin -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/movie.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/src/movie.o
In file included from src/movie.c:26:
In file included from src/pygame.h:106:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL.h:30:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_main.h:26:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_stdinc.h:30:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_config.h:34:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/SDL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/SDL_config_macosx.h:29:
/usr/include/AvailabilityMacros.h:110:14: warning: Building for Intel with Mac
      OS X Deployment Target < 10.4 is invalid. [-W#warnings]
            #warning Building for Intel with Mac OS X Deployment Target ...
             ^
1 warning generated.
/usr/bin/clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -g build/temp.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/src/movie.o -ls -lm -lp -le -lg -o build/lib.macosx-10.3-fat-2.7/pygame/movie.so -framework SDL -F/Library/Frameworks/
ld: library not found for -ls
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: do you have python development package installed?

Comment: no, I don't. that would do it?

Comment: You need Python source code (or atleast `Python.h` file) to compile it. In Linux I got `Python.h` in `python-dev` package installed by `apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: but many guides such as this one [link] http://bastibe.de/2011-03-04-installing-pygame-using-homebrew.html explain `Pygame` installation through `Homebrew` alone. I find it illogical to install full development packages, `macports` etc just in order to compile one single dependency, e.g.`smpeg`.

Comment: got it. did this: inside `pygame-1.9.1release`, `cd src, emacs scale_mmx64.c`. there I looked for all occurrences of `movsxl` and replaced them (two) with with `movslq`. then `sudo pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame` worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it. did this: inside '`pygame-1.9.1release`', '`cd src, emacs scale_mmx64.c`'. there I looked for all occurrences of '`movsxl`' and replaced them (two) with with '`movslq`'. then '`sudo pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame` worked'.

Comment: Rezzing a dead thread but this is still an issue to this day. `Error: Failed to download resource "smpeg"
Failure while executing: svn checkout -q --force svn://svn.icculus.org/smpeg/trunk /Library/Caches/Homebrew/smpeg--svn-HEAD`