# pygame mac homebrew, xz is not present or broken

Tags: macos, pygame, homebrew

I'm trying to get pygame installed, and followed a lot of tutorials to solve all occuring errors, but i can't get past these ones.

any help is appreciated.

```
brew install --HEAD smpeg
```

gives me the following error:

```
installing dependencies for smpeg: gobject-introspection, gdk-pixbuf,
==> Installing smpeg dependency: gobject-introspection
==> Building source; bottle blocked by python requirement
Error: /usr/local/opt/xz not present or broken
Please reinstall xz. Sorry :(
```

i'm trying to follow this turorial
http://bastibe.de/2011-03-04-installing-pygame-using-homebrew.html

```
brew install sdl, sdl_mixer, sdl_ttf, libpng, jpeg, sdl_image, portmidi
Error: No available formula for sdl,
```

and this question
[Pygame - smpeg does not find Python headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718372/pygame-smpeg-does-not-find-python-headers)

but im not sure how to 
`brew edit smpeg`, adding include.install Dir["*.h"] above the two end at the end.

what is the quickest way to get this tricky pygame thing installed?

Answer (score 1):

```
brew tap homebrew/python
brew install pygame
```

should be all you need to do.